# Sorting vector with forced arrangement of the elements in a grid

Tags: r, sorting

I have a vector with a given order:

```
p <- c("x", "y", "y",
       "y", "z", "a",
       "b", "b", "c", 
       "c", "c", "v")
```

I want the output to look "nice" in a grid with three columns, meaning that if three values are the same, they should be forced to be on the same line (`y` and `c`):

```
p.expected <- c( "y", "y", "y",
                 "x", "z", "a",
                 "b", "b", "v", 
                 "c", "c", "c")
```

I don't mind whether values of a group go up or down, but that change should be as small as possible.

For example, if I write original position of `y` values on Y axis as `{1, 2}`, then ideal lines for `y` row will be `1` or `2`. While `c` {3, 4} should appear in lines `3` or `4`.

Hence, this answer is too much of the change in the order:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "y"  "y"  "y" 
[2,] "c"  "c"  "c" 
[3,] "x"  "z"  "a" 
[4,] "b"  "b"  "v"
```

Here is a way to print the output:

```
split(p.expected, ceiling(seq_along(p.pretty)/3))
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit. How are you creating these vectors and most importantly, how are you printing them?

Comment: You can print it with: `split(p.expected, ceiling(seq_along(p.pretty)/3))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- c("x", "y", "y",
       "y", "z", "a",
       "b", "b", "c", 
       "c", "c", "v")
myfactor <- table(ordered(p, levels = unique(p)))

mynumbers <- rep(myfactor, myfactor)
```

Sort `myfactor` according to the decreasing order of `mynumbers`:

```
output <- myfactor[order(-mynumbers)]
```

You can see it better in a matrix:

```
matrix(output, ncol = 3, byrow = T)

##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "y"  "y"  "y" 
## [2,] "c"  "c"  "c" 
## [3,] "b"  "b"  "x" 
## [4,] "z"  "a"  "v"
```

Comment: Hi Davide, here values of `y` and `c` have moved to much compared to the original order. I am not sure how to define this. Possibly something like this: where possible two values of the group should not be moved from their line, if not possible, they should be moved to the line with other value. So position of the group on `Y` axis should not change.

Comment: Sorry, you can't change your mind after making a question. You said you didn't care about the change, then you edited and now you care. I proposed a way to solve your problem as you presented it originally, and I don't have time to re-program things. Have a nice day.

Comment: I did not care about the direction of the change. did not realise that it was not clear that I still care about the original order, hence the change. My expected output did not change, did it?

Comment: I edited my answer. I didn't get exactly your expected output, but I used an algorithm that also guarantees a minimal change in the initial vector. Hope it helps